# Ethernet (100 Mb/s) through relays

Tags: relay, transformer, ethernet

I'm trying to transmit Ethernet through relays. I'm using relays because I need them to switch to another signal path, and I'm specifically going to use relays and not other switching devices so that things are fail-safe and still provide a path when my device controlling the relays is off. So, I wonder if anybody out here knows can I safely transmit 100 Mb/s Ethernet through relays? I'm a bit worried because the spec says that Ethernet must be transferred through 100 Ω impedance (unshielded twisted pair).

1. Will the signal be OK?
2. Are there timing issues or any other issues with doing this?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? I bet there is a more reliable solution to your challenge.

Comment: Safety is not the issue. Data integrity and reliability are.

Comment: Maybe add the question whether you should be using one of those  "HF relays".

Comment: That is a bad idea. It might work like suggested but it most likley will not work! Just get a managed switch. You can tell it were to route data. IE Port1 incoming goes out Port4 (mornings) Port2 (evenings) or if Port1/2 Fail use fail over Port 3.  4Port Cisco ones about 70quid.. on ebay even cheaper. Seriously.. lan over relays = serious issues. If you still insist you need to shield the relays and use as small ones as possible. Like SMD size on a PCB. Not those large ones used 1980's Ford cars.

Comment: I am indeed going to use SMD size relays.

Comment: This sounds *so* Token-Ring... passive hubs full of relays,  a DC signal on the cable would pick up a relay to include the workstation in the ring.  But I quite agree this smells like an XY problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ethernet is surprisingly robust and you can use surprisingly bad cables before it starts to fail. So to send data through would probably work quite ok.

But when you switch the relays you would end up with a disconnect and a reconnect and those could cause the connected devices to behave strange since you on a logical level "moved the cable" from one device into another in a ms or so. And I am not sure how they would react to that...

But I get the feeling that there is another solution to your problem that will work better, even if this probably will work.

Answer (score 4):

(read this as an addendum to @Johan's answer.)

If the very short switchover time turns out to be a problem you can just add a second relay layer with a time delay *only* to the actively switched side (not the NC one).
This way you can chose the switchover time freely.

Keep in mind that you're adding another bit of non-twisted "wire" to the Ethernet cable, thus worsening the transmission capabilities a bit more.

Add a diode, a big Capacitor (and some other components) and even the switch back to the NC state in case of a power failure can be delayed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPyVxL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

For the first question about safely, the answer is yes. If you are using Power over Ethernet, check the voltage ratings on the relay.

It will likely work if the relay is at one end or the other. You can check to see if autonegotiation passed or it had to back down to 10 Mb/s.

Answer (score 0):

I answered the similar question in other thread (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/652025/313298) - in short: Give a try to TI TS3L501E or maybe PI3HDMI4... The TI one costs about 3$ on Mouser...

**EDIT:**
For clarification: According to TI tech stuff, it doesn’t matter if and how TS3L501E is used (with or without magnetics, etc.) because it’s passive FET switch… TI stated:

“The TS3L501E is a bidirectional passive FET switch so it doesn't matter where you put the switch in the system as long as the voltage and currents exposed to the device are within the recommended operating conditions.”

Ref:

1. https://e2e.ti.com/support/switches-multiplexers-group/switches-multiplexers/f/switches-multiplexers-forum/736451/ts3l501e-can-ts3l501e-being-put-after-the-transformer-of-the-connector
2. https://e2e.ti.com/support/switches-multiplexers-group/switches-multiplexers/f/switches-multiplexers-forum/967130/ts3l500ae-ts3l500ae-application-question

One possible solution:
[image]

Comment: Notice this only works on the PHY side, not bare media. Explanation here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/641151/ethernet-multiplexing-using-hcf4066

Comment: This device can be used to replace mechanical relays in LAN applications. (As written in the datasheet) So it’s designed for bare media...

Comment: This answer again assumes that the chip you suggest can be placed before the magnetics, as it can't work on the cable side of magnetics of an existing device.

Comment: Don’t blame people: https://e2e.ti.com/support/switches-multiplexers-group/switches-multiplexers/f/switches-multiplexers-forum/736451/ts3l501e-can-ts3l501e-being-put-after-the-transformer-of-the-connector No offense…

Comment: “The TS3L501E is a  bidirectional passive FET switch so it doesn't matter where you put the switch in the system as long as the voltage and currents exposed to the device are within the recommended operating conditions.”

Comment: Another thread (and picture): https://e2e.ti.com/support/switches-multiplexers-group/switches-multiplexers/f/switches-multiplexers-forum/676069/ts3l500ae-10-100-1000base-t-applications and this example: https://e2e.ti.com/support/switches-multiplexers-group/switches-multiplexers/f/switches-multiplexers-forum/967130/ts3l500ae-ts3l500ae-application-question

Comment: Notice the very cagey language: "as long as it's within limits" or to that effect. e2e's service engineers (or maybe they're just techs, I don't know) are merely front line customer service, they don't know very much about the products themselves and aren't going to tell you not to buy their products, even if something doesn't work very well.

Comment: @JiříAltman Yes, and Ethernet interface requires withstanding 1500 V of voltage over the magnetics, and the cable side must be isolated from any common reference. Power over Ethernet will also kill the switch chip. So the TI people called "Mastermind" and "Genius" are not in theory wrong, they say it can be used as long as the  chip is used within operating conditions. They are just forum people to answer quickly so it looks like you get free support, they really have no clue about Ethernet. So yeah, no offense, like you said. So don't blindly believe what you read on internet.