# Will relays work to build a physical ethernet "killswitch"

Tags: ethernet

In order to incorporate a networked device into an automated test framework, I am looking at building a small number of ethernet "killswitch" boards that will simulate physically disconnecting the device.

In order to keep things simple and cheap, I'm hoping to use either a single or pair of relays to switch one core of one of both of the ethernet pairs. Normally the entire board will be unpowered. Application of a 5V signal will switch the relays(s) to the NO position and break the connection.

My questions are:

1. Are the relays in their NC state likely to interfere with normal ethernet signals?
   [This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/44974/ethernet-100-mb-s-through-relays) suggests the answer is yes, but I'm wondering if there are particular things I should be aware of.
2. Will breaking one ethernet pair be sufficient to "disconnect" the device, or do I need to switch both?

I'm a competent electronic engineer, but I don't really know anything about the details of ethernet. This is 100Mbps ethernet (not gigabit).

Comment: There are many different kinds of ethernet. Which one are you referring to? Some are much more forgiving than others in terms of signal integrity.

Comment: have you considered using a cheap 4 port ethernet switch ... turn it off to disconnect

Comment: Added ethernet speed to the question.

Comment: I think using four-port switches would take up too much room and power supplies - there will be quite a few devices under test in the end. Worth exploring the idea though.

Comment: you could also use a managed switch and selectively turn down ports

Comment: @jfowkes how "low level" does the simulated disconnect have to be? Because this really sounds like the job for a *managed switch* where you can simply turn off individual ports. For the ancient 100 Mbit/s Fast Ethernet standard, they are ebay ware – everyone has been getting rid of theirs for the last decades. [Example of one](https://www.ebay.de/itm/D-Link-DES-3225G-24-Port-Switch-24x-FastEthernet-1000Base-SX-managed/324315047845?epid=1378147323&hash=item4b82aee7a5%3Ag%3AToYAAOSwgj9elLqq&LH_Auction=1&LH_ItemCondition=3000)

Comment: Ideally it would be as close as possible to someone physically pulling the jack out of the socket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you are testing, but Ethernet should really have controlled 100 ohm differential impedance, so a random big clunky relay in the middle would break that property. Also PCB trace lengths should be matched.

There are some RF relays that can be used for this, and in fact not entirely RF rated relays have worked fine with 16-level 500 Msymbols/sec PAM interface.

Perhaps in your case it would be best to make a device with Ethernet magnetics at input and output, and put an analog mux between the transformers, and make sure the analog mux can switch at Ethernet speeds. That's how some PC laptop docking stations work. These analog muxes for Ethernet are also called "LAN signal switch chips" to distinguish them from the actual switch chips.

Comment: Yeah I considered "proper" multiplexer ICs but was hoping to get away with a simpler solution if possible

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago, where I work, we've been asked to provide such a device to a customer, who was testing some ring redundancy protocols in industrial Ethernet. He tried using media converters for the job, and got skewed results. The ring switch vendor claimed that any media converter (same thing for a dumb switch), inserted in the L2 links involved in the ring path, will break subtle aspects of the protocol (even if it doesn't eat the specific management frames outright) and will yield weird behavior, which will make the automated test fail.

The Ethernet flavour at the time was 100Mb as well = just two pairs and the required bandwidth is something under 100 MHz. The relay I used was an RY-12W by Takamisawa, which is specifically a signal relay. I recall taking special care to find a relay that should be able to pass the bandwidth through. In my case, I believe the relays are connected "normally open", and the contacts close = link gets connected when power is applied to relay coils. The schematic and board are not much to write home about, I can do better now. Each switching device actually had a small mains power supply transformer, because the "test lab" preferred to switch 230V AC as a control voltage (it fitted into the original design of their test rig). I'm attaching screenshots for illustration, the eagle source is available upon request...

[image: disruptor schematic]

[image: disruptor board]

Come to think about it, the sin on part of the testlab could've been, that they used the media converters in pairs, and perhaps the opposite converter did not get powered down and did not support link fault passthrough, i.e. the link would remain apparently up. Or maybe it was indeed something about the management frames...
Anyway after rewiring the test bench using our relay switches, the ring topology under test started to pass.

The 100Mb Ethernet needs just two pairs - at pins 1+2 and 3+6 in the RJ45 (typically the orange and green pair in standard B color coding) and needs about 60 MHz of bandwidth. Gigabit Ethernet OTOH runs over all four pairs and needs slightly more bandwidth - some sources claim 125 MHz.

And you may be right that having the link cleanly broken across all the conductors may not be the typical failure scenario. Cold joints would typically result in a gradual decline of transmission line quality in a single pair. Miscellaneous crimping errors typically affect a single pair too.

Comment: Basically all we need to simulate is unplugging the cable, but obviously if cutting one conductor is enough that's preferable to a solution that cuts all four! Thanks for your schematic, that's very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Such devices were used in legacy gateways to high security environments where they periodically switched a simple and assured messaging proxy between high and low side environments where two way message traffic was required; but to prevent a direct path. These 'break before make switches' used a relay to simply break the two active ethernet pairs from one side, and then made them to the 'other side' where ethernet physical protocols and DHCP sorted out the rest. Ethernet at 10Mbit/s worked very well, and 100Mbit/s was at times a bit flaky.  To get these to work reliably and force the physical layer to 10Mbit/s a small Netgear hub on the common part worked well. If working at higher speeds you will need to maintain the transmission line characteristics and avoid reflections which will be horrendous from such a relay: I suggest that any such relay is physically very close (centimetres) from a small switch on either side of the relay.  Obviously if using this in high EMF strength environments the earthing of all sides is important.

For the soldering iron junkies: to reduce reflections this would best be created as a classic birds nest with no circuit board and the ethernet twisted pairs soldered direct to the relay terminals, then place into a box and pour in the epoxy potting compound.  It will then look soooo professional, and work!

Another technique would be to use a fibre LAN connector and simply break the optical path in some way.  This is very similar to how data diodes work, where there is only a data path in one direction and UDP traffic is used.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you can try **TI TS3L501E**:

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts3l501e.pdf?ts=1675043956148&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTS3L501E

It’s an 11-Channel SPDT/22-Bit to 11-Bit Multiplexer and Demultiplexer **Ethernet LAN Switch With Power-Down Mode** from Texas Instruments… It supports 10/100/1000BASE-T(X) and costs cca 3$… Or you can try also PI3HDMI4 - it’s for HDMI, but it looks pretty similar (4x differential 2:1 MUX to 6Gbps I guess)…

One disadvantage is that it’s manufactured only in WQFN SMT package which is not good for hand soldering … but with a good soldering iron, it’s doable… I recommend make and order PCB from China - they will send a bunch of boards for few bucks… don’t forget to order stencil also! It’s cheap and very helpful, especially with such a small pin pitch…

Comment: Notice this only works on the PHY side, not bare media; it isn't clear if this would suffice for this application. Explanation here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/641151/ethernet-multiplexing-using-hcf4066

Comment: It’s simple multiplexor... Why do you think it won’t work? In datasheet is written: 9.1 Application Information
There are many Local Area Network (LAN) applications in which the ethernet hubs or controllers have a limited number of I/Os or need to route signals from a single ethernet PHY to multiple ethernet jacks. The TS3L501E solution can effectively expand the limited I/Os by switching between multiple ethernet jacks to interface them to a single ethernet PHY.

Comment: Btw. on the first page of the datasheet is explicitly written: This device can be used to replace mechanical relays in LAN applications. So it’s designed for bare media...

Comment: @JiříAltman TimWilliams is right. Ethernet is an interface with electrical isolation made with transformers. So the chip can't be used for switching Ethernet on the bare media or cable side of transformers/connectors. These muxes can only be used between the Ethernet chip and transformers (which may be integrated into connectors).

Comment: That’s correct, but it can be used in transformerless configuration (at least for lower speed): https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla327/slla327.pdf?ts=1674979779770

Comment: So I verified that TS3L501E don't need any magnetic: https://e2e.ti.com/support/switches-multiplexers-group/switches-multiplexers/f/switches-multiplexers-forum/909139/ts3l501e-transformer-less-approach-for-gigabit-application So “the TS3L501E does not require any magnetics to operate.  This is a passive FET switch and can support any signal as long as the voltages are within the recommended operating condition and the switch’s bandwidth limitations wont impact the protocol passing through the device.”

Comment: @JiříAltman Sure the switch does not need magntics, but it also can't be used between magnetics. So you can't use it to switch cables of existing devices that already have magnetics. So it won't work for this question where you need to simulate uplugging a cable.

Comment: Can you please explain why it won't work between two magnetics? How it impacts the communication? Did you read the datasheet? It definitely can be used as a switch on bare metal - no matter if there are transformers or not... The same way as transformerless PHYs can be connected together or if you have transformer only on one PHY... Check another discussion: https://e2e.ti.com/support/switches-multiplexers-group/switches-multiplexers/f/switches-multiplexers-forum/736451/ts3l501e-can-ts3l501e-being-put-after-the-transformer-of-the-connector

Comment: The problem is that Ethernet media operates at arbitrary voltages: nominally it is isolated, but transient phenomena can push into the ~kV, and this switch is only rated for ESD (6kV HBM tops). The abs. max. ranges show it cannot support any CM voltage between channels, certainly not the 50V+ of PoE or the 1.5kV rating of transformer-coupled media; these need transformers to handle them first. You could make a switch box with extra transformers surrounding this device, at fairly minor impact to overall signal quality.

Comment: @JiříAltman I don't need to read the data sheet, because I know how Ethernet works, and thus no IC switch or mux can be used on the cable side, so this chip can't be any different from any other ICs in this regads. It won't work, and now on two questions about Ethernet switching you are claiming it will work.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for your answer - that’s fair enough and I agree with your explanation… Even though those IC switches can be used without magnetics, it’s IMHO bad, especially if the resulting solution should meet certain standards...

Comment: @Justme I don't agree... If Ethernet uses relatively poor-looking connections with RJ45 connectors or punch impact Cat5E keystones, the use of such a switch (and thrifty design of course - ideally with appropriate magnetics) should work with minor impact to overall quality...