# Ethernet multiplexing using HCF4066

Tags: microcontroller, ethernet

This is a simple test circuit as a hobby. I want to create a basic circuit to multiplex Ethernet traffic as shown below. In the actual circuit two ICs will be used for required pins.

[image]

The idea is to switch the Ethernet b/w two ports. Speed is not a concern at this point. My questions are:

1. As Ethernet signals are differential, so if we apply +-5 V to the HCF4066's power pins, will it work?
2. I tried to control a simple LED from an external power supply via a 4066 IC, but even the switch is disconnected, I see a dim light in the LED. The reason was that I forgot to have a common ground between the LED's power supply and the 4066's power supply. Since Ethernet has no ground pin, will it still work?
3. Is it possible with tS3A27518EPWR, which doesn't support negative voltages as required by Ethernet pins?

Comment: It would help to evaluate how to do that if you would explain what is the purpose of Ethernet switching and why it must be done. Perhaps for what you want to do is a better option than switching Ethernet.

Comment: @Justme i want to connect beagle bone black board to two networks one by one. Want to do it without human interactions

Comment: Again, why must you switch between two networks to begin with? And any reasons why you can't put another network interface so you don't need switching? Or a configurable Ethernet router/switch? Or buy another Beagle Bone Black for the other network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going with 5 V relays, as it has almost 0 capacitance/resistance and is just a short circuit. The only problem is that for 10/100 Mbps four relays are required, but for 1000 Mbps we will need eight relays.

Comment: This does not answer your original question.

Answer (score 3):

HCF4066 doesn't have nearly enough common mode range or ESD immunity for switching media (cables).  It may work, or it may not.  It may end up damaged and non-working.  It almost certainly won't enumerate gigabit speeds (but probably would work well enough for 10/100, at least for short cable lengths).

Better to use a relay.

Even better still, a managed switch to just disable a given port -- or black/white-list the device(s) by MAC or IP or, whatever is connected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May you recommend any other option that can serve the purpose. Relays are quite bulky and i was trying to avoid them.

Comment: @IjazAhmad You're doing it at the wrong point. An analog switch can be used with transformers, but this is most practical right beside the PHY(s). In which case you might as well get a switch IC, put transformers and other support components on it, and call it done. But then you can go out and buy a complete switch unit for much less bother.

Comment: Do you know/recommend any switch that can be controlled by a microcontroller etc.

Comment: Going with relays option...

Answer (score 1):

1. No, it won't work. Even at 15V supply the switch has an ON resistance  is typically 125 ohms. Putting 125 ohms in series with both signals of a pair that is terminated into 100 ohms will likely be more than enough for it not to work.
2. Ethernet signals are specified to float but if they are passed through a chip then the chip must float too. But it won't work because HCF4066 is a wrong chip for this, see point 1.
3. This chip might work but it would need to have a floating power supply.

Relays may cause problems too unless expensive relays intended for high speed signals are used.

How to do it properly depends on why you want to do it.

Comment: I want to connect beaglebone black to two networks.

Answer (score 0):

The PI3L110 from diodes might work for your application. It has 2kv of immunity, 2-3pf of capacitance on the pins and bandwidth of up to 350mhz